# Increment number of amount with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to increment a number inside an element on page. But I need the number to include a comma while the increment only will increase 1 digit per second.

I have the code working but I'm kinda stuck not sure where to set the increment which only increase 1 digit per second (eg: `10,100,040` then `10,100,041` and so on)

```
<script></script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

```js
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
$({
    someValue: 40
}).animate({
    someValue: 45000000
}, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing', // can be anything
    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
    }
});

function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return "$" + val;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interval would be much more appropriate to achieve this instead of jQuery's `animate()` method, which is intended to amend the DOM. Try this:

```js
var start = 40, end = 45000000;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var $el = $('#el');
    var val = $el.data('value') || 40;
    $el.text(commaSeparateNumber(++val)).data('value', val)
    
    if (val >= end)
       clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);

function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
  while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
    val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  }
  return "$" + val;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el">$40</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rory , your code is working perfectly , may i know how to set the increase time per second ?

Comment: Change the `1000` parameter in the `setInterval`. That's the delay between iterations in milliseconds. Are you sure you want to make it longer? The counter will already last 1.5 years at a 1 second delay

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to animate the object... This is weird. Basically, the animate method is used ([according to Spec](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) to animate some css styles of DOM element.

That's how it usually used:

```
$('#el').animate({ top: '10px'}, 100, function () { /* on complete function */ });
```

Your task could be solved by making something like this:

```
var value = 40;
var end = 45000000;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    value++;
    $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(value));

    if (value >= end) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```